# JSON is valid, but JSON.parse(jsonObject) return error

Tags: javascript, php, json, yii

I write web site using Yii framework. I need get all data from DB in Yii, and I wrote some code for this:

```
var response = 
    <?php 
        function getAllDataTable() {
            $connection = Yii::app()->db;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM data";
            $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);

            $rows = $command->queryAll();

            return $rows;
        }

        function getJsonFromRows($rows) {
            $json = "{ ";

            foreach ($rows as $rowIndex => $rowData) {
                if ($rowIndex !== 0)
                    $json .= ", ";

                $json .= "\"row".$rowIndex."\": {";

                $colIndex = 0;
                foreach ($rowData as $columnHeader => $cellValue) {
                    if ($colIndex++ !== 0)
                        $json .= ", ";
                    $json .= "\"".$columnHeader."\"".": "."\"".$cellValue."\"";
                }

                $json .= "} ";
            }

            $json.="}";

            return $json;
        }

        $rows = getAllDataTable();

        echo getJsonFromRows($rows);
     ?>;

var data = JSON.parse(response);

console.log("data: \"" + data + "\"");
```

I try to use JSON to do it.
This is code from debugger:

```
var response = { "row0": {"year": "2001", "discipline": "some discipline", "theme": "some theme", "pair": "some pair"} , "row1": {"year": "2001", "discipline": "some discipline", "theme": "some theme", "pair": "some pair"} };
var data = JSON.parse(response);
console.log("data: \"" + data + "\"");
```

This is errors, which I got:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data material:53:18

Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1:0

Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.
```

I check result of php script on the many sites such this:
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
my json object is correct but JSON.parse(jsonObject) return error. Why?

P.S. This theme isn't duplicate, I see all this posts:
[JSON Lint says it's valid but JSON.parse throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200588/json-lint-says-its-valid-but-json-parse-throws-error)
[jQuery IE9 JSON.SyntaxError parseerror, but JSON is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182732/jquery-ie9-json-syntaxerror-parseerror-but-json-is-valid)
[JSON.parse Error on Valid JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563092/json-parse-error-on-valid-json)
[check if required JSON is valid - node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615098/check-if-required-json-is-valid-node)
[JSON.parse error on a seemingly valid JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635585/json-parse-error-on-a-seemingly-valid-json)

Comment: It is valid or it is not valid. Is JSON Lint *really* says it is valid then you're using different data. Go back to (and correct) the assumptions: *JSON is text*. In the code shown, **there is no JSON**, but rather assignment of a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: Also, do not create JSON/XML/etc by hand. You're bound to get it wrong at least some of the time or with some data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP

```
    function getJsonFromRows($rows) {
        $json = array();

        foreach ($rows as $rowIndex => $rowData) {
            $tmp = array();
            foreach ($rowData as $columnHeader => $cellValue) {
                $tmp[$columnHeader] =$cellValue;
            }

            $json["$rowIndex"] = $tmp;
        }

        return json_encode($json);
    }
```

Now if you will do JSON.parse on the response it will convert.

Answer (score 4):

[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) expects a string to be passed as first argument.

In other words you already have a javascript object. JSON parse is used if you have a *string* and want to convert to a *JavaScript object*.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an object to JSON.parse instead of a string.  Consider if you even need to parse it, as your `var response` is probably already the object you want.

Answer (score 0):

As others have been saying, you are trying to parse an object.

JSON.stringify() Converts an object into a string.
JSON.parse() Converts a JSON string into an object.

Here is a fiddle showing this is the case with your code. 
http://jsfiddle.net/wpwelch/39hx5oy0/

```
<div id="jsonString"></div>
<br />
<div id="jsObject"></div>  

 var test = { "row0": {"year": "2001", "discipline": "some discipline", "theme": "some theme", "pair": "some pair"} , "row1": {"year": "2001", "discipline": "some discipline", "theme": "some theme", "pair": "some pair"} };
    strEcho = JSON.stringify(test);
    objRef = test.row0.year; // Works because var test is already an object
    $("#jsonString").html(strEcho); // Works because .stringify() is working with a valid JSON object.
    $("#jsObject").html(objRef); // This shows the year 2001
```

In your code, you can edit this line

```
var data = JSON.parse(response);
```

to be

```
var data = response;
```

and everything will work since you already have a valid object.